# migrate power bi collection to power bi embeded

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I tried to follow the article to migrate power bi collection to power bi embedded ([msdn article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/migrate-from-powerbi-embedded)). However, I got stuck very quickly.

For example, in our app, we use these nuget packages (Microsoft.PowerBI.Api and powerbi.core), and these are some of our usages:

```
client.Reports.GetReportsAsync(this.workspaceCollection, this.workspaceId)

client.Reports.DeleteReportAsync(this.workspaceCollection, this.workspaceId, report.Id);

client.Imports.PostImportFileWithHttpMessage(this.workspaceCollection,this.workspaceId,File.OpenRead(localPath), "Main Report");

client.Datasets.GetGatewayDatasourcesAsync(workspaceCollection, workspaceId, dataset.Id);

client.Gateways.PatchDatasourceAsync(workspaceCollection,workspaceId,datasources.Value[0].GatewayId,datasources.Value[0].Id,
delta);

client.Datasets.GetDatasetsAsync(workspaceCollection, workspaceId);
```

I can download all reports and move to power BI embedded, but as workspace collection will be retired, will we still be able to use above methods? If not, are there any alternative functions to use?

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question in powerbi forum as well. In case it helps anyone, you can't use above methods any more, instead, we will need to call the REST API directly. [The powerbi forum post is here](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/migrate-power-bi-collection-to-power-bi-embeded/m-p/430129#M13095)

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation for migration: https://pbiwebprod-docs.azurewebsites.net/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-migrate-from-powerbi-embedded/

A cool video that might help also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHxEn0orpdI

The REST APIs for the migrated content is very similar. Only difference would be referring to the data via `groupId` and not `workspaceCollectionId`.